# Converting a Jar-URI into a nio.Path

Tags: java, url, path, uri, classloader

I'm having trouble coverting from a URI to a `nio.Path` in the general case. Given a URI with multiple schemas, I wish to create a single `nio.Path` instance to reflect this URI.

```
    //setup
    String jarEmbeddedFilePathString = "jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/OurSoftware/OurJar_x86_1.0.68.220.jar!/com/our_company/javaFXViewCode.fxml";
    URI uri = URI.create(jarEmbeddedFilePathString);

    //act
    Path nioPath = Paths.get(uri);

    //assert --any of these are acceptable
    assertThat(nioPath).isEqualTo("C:/Program Files (x86)/OurSoftware/OurJar_x86_1.0.68.220.jar/com/our_company/javaFXViewCode.fxml");
    //--or assertThat(nioPath).isEqualTo("/com/our_company/javaFXViewCode.fxml");
    //--or assertThat(nioPath).isEqualTo("OurJar_x86_1.0.68.220.jar!/com/our_company/javaFXViewCode.fxml")
    //or pretty well any other interpretation of jar'd-uri-to-path any reasonable person would have.
```

This code currently throws `FileSystemNotFoundException` on the `Paths.get()` call.

The actual reason for this conversion is to ask the resulting path about things regarding its package location and file name --so in other words, as long as the resulting path object preserves the `...com/our_company/javaFXViewCode.fxml` portion, then its still very convenient for us to use the NIO Path object.

Most of this information is actually used for debugging, so it would not be impossible for me to retrofit our code to avoid use of Paths in this particular instance and instead use URI's or simply strings, but that would involve a bunch of retooling for methods already conveniently provided by the `nio.Path` object.

I've started digging into [the file system provider API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/filesystemprovider.html) and have been confronted with more complexity than I wish to deal with for such a small thing. Is there a simple way to convert from a class-loader provided URI to a path object corresponding to OS-understandable traversal in the case of the URI pointing to a non-jar file, and not-OS-understandable-but-still-useful traversal in the case where the path would point to a resource inside a jar (or for that matter a zip or tarball)?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3):

A Java [`Path`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) belongs to a [`FileSystem`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html). A file system is implemented by a [`FileSystemProvider`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/spi/FileSystemProvider.html).

Java comes with two file system providers: One for the operating system (e.g. `WindowsFileSystemProvider`), and one for zip files (`ZipFileSystemProvider`). These are internal and should not be accessed directly.

To get a `Path` to a file inside a Jar file, you need to get (create) a `FileSystem` for the content of the Jar file. You can then get a `Path` to a file in that file system.

First, you'll need to parse the Jar URL, which is best done using the `JarURLConnection`:

```
URL jarEntryURL = new URL("jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/OurSoftware/OurJar_x86_1.0.68.220.jar!/com/our_company/javaFXViewCode.fxml");
JarURLConnection jarEntryConn = (JarURLConnection) jarEntryURL.openConnection();
URL jarFileURL = jarEntryConn.getJarFileURL(); // file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/OurSoftware/OurJar_x86_1.0.68.220.jar
String entryName = jarEntryConn.getEntryName(); // com/our_company/javaFXViewCode.fxml
```

Once you have those, you can create a `FileSystem` and get a `Path` to the jar'd file. Remember that `FileSystem` is an open resource and needs to be closed when you are done with it:

```
try (FileSystem jarFileSystem = FileSystems.newFileSystem(jarPath, null)) {
    Path entryPath = jarFileSystem.getPath(entryName);
    System.out.println("entryPath: " + entryPath); // com/our_company/javaFXViewCode.fxml
    System.out.println("parent: " + entryPath.getParent()); // com/our_company
}
```

Comment: ++ for the "FileSystem needs to be closed"